# Poor performing Query -Tsql execution plan - estimated number of rows =1 Paste the Plan

Tags: t-sql, performance, performance-tuning, query-performance

The query and the execution plan are available at the link below.

This is from vendor application that I support. I know that there has to be a better way to write this code but the vendor says that it is the best that they can do.

I have a problem with the number of joins, the indiscriminate use of `nolock`, the `top(1)` and the use of the subqueries.

I am looking for a recommendation on how to do this better as the vendor does not appear to have the ability to improve on the query.

This query negatively impacts the performance of my production environment. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJlq-ERAb

Comment: I can see that you posted the estimated execution plan. Any chance we can get to have a look at the actual execution plan?

Comment: I have uploaded the actual execution plan unfortunately it is during low volume part of the day    https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyCv7zJkz

Comment: You left out using `SELECT *` instead of an explicit list of columns needed - or, are *all* of those columns actually needed?